# iphone - How to extract youtube links from a html?

Tags: iphone, youtube

1. Can anyone tell me how to extract YouTube links from a html source using objective-c?
2. And also, how to get big preview image for a YouTube link?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use a regex framework like [RegexKitLite](http://regexkit.sourceforge.net/RegexKitLite/) or [AGRegex](http://sourceforge.net/projects/agkit/) to parse the HTML source you have anda extract the link and the image url that you need.

although, you are probably better off using the [YouTube APIs](http://code.google.com/apis/youtube/overview.html) and save you the headache of html parsing.

Comment: Youtube API does not provide a way to EXTRACT youtube link